# Enviar información de una ventana a otra con electron (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Llevo unos días aprendiendo cosas acerca de Electron que es un framework que sirve para crear aplicaciones con node.js y Javascript y me he estancado.

El problema es que necesito enviar información desde la página principal a una nueva ventana que se abre dándole click a un botón html de la ventana principal, o sea no desde el proceso principal index.js, si no desde la ventana principal index.html.

Según tengo entendido, si deseas abrir una ventana desde el menú contextual has de hacerlo mediante el proceso principal (index.js) y desde ahí se usa el módulo ipcMain, ya lo he probado desde ahí y funciona, pero lo que quiero es hacerlo mediante un evento desde una ventana a otra.

Lo estoy haciendo así, no sé si está correcto. El caso es que no recibo nada en la ventana nueva. Llevo varias horas mirando y buscando información y no consigo aclararme, ¿me podéis echar una mano?

**index.html**

```
const { ipcRenderer, webContents } = require('electron');

var botonA=document.getElementById('boton');

botonA.addEventListener('click', function(){

    abrirVentanaNueva();
}); 


let ventanaNueva;

var mensaje='ABCDEFG';

function abrirVentanaNueva(){

    ventanaNueva = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 445,
        height:700,
        title: 'Ventana nueva',
        //resizable:false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });


    ventanaNueva.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'ventana-nueva.html'),
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true


    }));

    ventanaNueva.webContents.send('enviar', mensaje);


    ventanaNueva.on('close', function(){


    ventanaNueva=null;

} );



}
```

**ventana-nueva.html**

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;


ipcRenderer.on('enviar', function(e, datos){ 


console.log(datos);



});
```

Answer (score 1):

Es que no te llega mensaje, por lo que entendí de tu explicación. El problema es que estas intentando mandar un mensaje cuando la ventana todavía no se ha iniciado esta fue mi solución:

Al crear la instancia de BrowserWindow le agrege una función al evento 'ready-to-show', que ahí es donde le mando el mensaje ***:***

**index.html**

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

var botonA = document.getElementById('boton');

botonA.addEventListener('click', function(){
  /* En vez de crearla en el renderer la mandas al main 
    que la cree
  abrirVentanaNueva();*/
  ipcRenderer.send('crear-nueva-ventana',"Esto es una prueba para el mensaje")
});
```

**main.js**

```
const {ipcMain, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let nuevaVentana;
ipcMain.on('crear-nueva-ventana',(e, mensaje) => {
  nuevaVentana = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 445,
    height:700,
    title: 'Ventana nueva',
    //resizable:false,
    webPreferences:{
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  });
  nuevaVentana.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname,'src', 'ventana-nueva.html'),
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true
  }));
  /* Función asociada al evento 'ready-to-show'*/
  nuevaVentana.on('ready-to-show', () =>{
    /* Despues que ocurre el evento se manda el mensaje*/
    nuevaVentana.webContents.send('enviar-mensaje',mensaje)
  })
  nuevaVentana.on('close', () => {
    nuevaVentana = null
  });
})
```

**nueva-ventana.html**

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

ipcRenderer.on('enviar-mensaje', (e, mensaje) => {
    alert(mensaje);
});
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/248464)

Comment: gracias, ya encontre la respuesta ya la monto

Comment: @Pritep para evitar que tus publicaciones sean reportadas como ocurrió con esta considera solo usar por favor el espacio de respuestas para publicar soluciones a la pregunta planteada, por otro lado si antes de eso quieres preguntar algo espera a tener 50 de rep. Y podrás comentar

Comment: es que habia preguntado algo en una respuesta y Candid Moe, me puso el comentario, después encontre la solución y edite mi comentario quitando la pregunta y poniendo la respuesta, pero la que esta montada ahora mismo sí es la respuesta. ¿Cual fue mi error esta vez? es que soy nuevo

Comment: No tuviste error de hecho ahora es una respuesta en forma y que seguro será útil, lo que ocurre es que el primer comentario que te dejaron es por qué inicialmente solo publicaste una pregunta y tú aporte fue reportado (*el texto que te dejaron es genérico y forma parte de los que el sistema nos permite colocar cuando las publicaciones por alguna razón quedan dentro de la cola de revisión*) por lo que corría el riesgo de ser eliminado, aquí puedes leer [answer] y hacer el [tour] para familiarizarte más